Added an element in forest
Could you help me add the curved arrow that goes from alpha to beta on this figure?
It would be simpler with tikzpicture, but with forest I don't really see it.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{% common styles of tikz pictures elements
  treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
                     draw, align=center, 
                     minimum height=2ex, text depth=0.25ex,
                     top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
  root/.style     = {treenode, font=\Large\rmfamily, bottom color=red!30},
  env/.style      = {treenode, font=\ttfamily\normalsize}
}
\forestset{
  bedge/.style    = {edge label={node[midway, sloped, font=\footnotesize, below]{$#1$}}},
  aedge/.style    = {edge label={node[midway, sloped, font=\footnotesize, above]{$#1$}}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
    l sep=10em, s sep=6em,
    edge={-latex},
    math content,
    grow'=0, 
    if level=0{root}{env}
}
[, 
    [A, aedge={\alpha}
        [B, aedge={\beta}]
        [\overline{B}, bedge={1 - \beta}]
    ]
    [\overline{A}, bedge={1 - \alpha}
        [B, aedge={\gamma}]
        [T, bedge={1 - \gamma}]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}

The result :


Welcome to TeX.SE.

One way is to name the label nodes and then \draw the arrow.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{% common styles of tikz pictures elements
  treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
                     draw, align=center, 
                     minimum height=2ex, text depth=0.25ex,
                     top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
  root/.style     = {treenode, font=\Large\rmfamily, bottom color=red!30},
  env/.style      = {treenode, font=\ttfamily\normalsize}
}
\forestset{
  bedge/.style    = {edge label={node[midway, sloped, font=\footnotesize, below]{$#1$}}},
  aedge/.style    = {edge label={node[midway, sloped, font=\footnotesize, above]{$#1$}}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
    l sep=10em, s sep=6em,
    edge={-latex},
    math content,
    grow'=0, 
    if level=0{root}{env}
}
[, 
    [A, edge label={node[name=AA, midway, sloped, font=\footnotesize, above]{$\alpha$}}
        [B, edge label={node[name=BB, midway, sloped, font=\footnotesize, above]{$\beta$}}]
        [\overline{B}, bedge={1 - \beta}]
    ]
    [\overline{A}, bedge={1 - \alpha}
        [B, aedge={\gamma}]
        [T, bedge={1 - \gamma}]
    ]
]
\draw[-Latex](AA) to[bend left=45]node[above, sloped, font=\small]{$p(A\cap B)=\alpha\beta$} (BB);
\end{forest}

\end{document}


A more general version of Sandy's answer is to build the node name into the edge style directly. This way you can refer to any edge label with the node name that uses that edge:  L-<node-name>.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{% common styles of tikz pictures elements
  treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
                     draw, align=center, 
                     minimum height=2ex, text depth=0.25ex,
                     top color=white, bottom color=blue!20},
  root/.style     = {treenode, font=\Large\rmfamily, bottom color=red!30},
  env/.style      = {treenode, font=\ttfamily\normalsize}
}
\forestset{
  bedge/.style    = {edge label={node (L-\forestoption{name}) [midway, sloped, font=\footnotesize, below]{$#1$}}},
  aedge/.style    = {edge label={node (L-\forestoption{name}) [midway, sloped, font=\footnotesize, above]{$#1$}}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
    l sep=10em, s sep=6em,
    edge={-latex},
    math content,
    grow'=0, 
    if level=0{root}{env}
}
[, 
    [A, aedge={\alpha},name=A
        [B, aedge={\beta},name=B]
        [\overline{B}, bedge={1 - \beta}]
    ]
    [\overline{A}, bedge={1 - \alpha}
        [B, aedge={\gamma}]
        [T, bedge={1 - \gamma}]
    ]
 ]
\draw [-latex,bend left=45] (L-A)  to node[above, sloped, font=\small]{$p(A\cap B)=\alpha\beta$} (L-B);
\end{forest}
\end{document}


